# Firebase RTDB: Filtering by timestamp issue

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Querying in Firebase RTDB looks simple, but I have a problem. Database structure see below. I need filter trips by `finishTime`. For all my queries I'm gettin all nodes inside `trips/*` with no filter applied. What is the issue? Thanks.

[image]

Path: `timeline/240303/trips`

Queries:

1. Returns all nodes

```
val q = database.getReference(path).orderByChild("finishTime").startAt(limitFinish.toDouble)
```

2. Also returns all nodes, but expected no nodes

```
val q = database.getReference(path).orderByChild("finishTime").startAt(Long.MAX_VALUE.toDouble())
```

Request code:

```
    private const val KEY_TIMELINE_TRIPS = "timeline/%s/trips"

    val ref = database.getReference(String.format(KEY_TIMELINE_TRIPS, dayTag))

    val query = if (limitStart > Long.MIN_VALUE && limitFinish == Long.MAX_VALUE)
        ref.orderByChild("startTime").endAt(limitStart.toDouble())
    else if (limitStart == Long.MIN_VALUE && limitFinish < Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        ref.orderByChild("finishTime").startAt(limitFinish.toDouble())
    } else
        ref

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener { task -> ... }
```

Comment: What is `path`?  Please edit the question to be clear what the query is.

Comment: @DougStevenson `path` is `timeline/240303/trips`

Comment: Please edit the question so it's absolutely clear.  Important information should not be buried in comments.

Comment: What is the value of  `limitFinish.toDouble`? And why are you converting a number to a floating point number since the value of `finishTime` is a long value?

Comment: When you edit to address Alex' request, can you also show the code that executes the query and processes the results (ideally just logs them)?

Comment: @AlexMamo I had to convert timestamp to Double by RTDB API reason: `startAt` takes only String, Double and Boolean. Maybe this conversion produce the issue, but how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, did you try to pass a long value? Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: @AlexMamo I can't pass Long to `startAt`

Comment: Did you also try with hard-code value? With a number, not a floating point number.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added my request snippet, please check it, thanks. I can hardcode only Double, because `startAt` method takes only Double numerals

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can I filtering data in Android using `Long`  at all?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database stored numbers as double values, so there's no API to pass a long value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen docs says RTDB can store Long data too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data

Comment: So I still can't filtering cloud Long timestamps using timestamps convertion into Double in my app

Comment: Can you reproduce with just a hard-coded value? Like: `ref.orderByChild("finishTime").startAt(1709424900001).get()....` and then print the results and show us that code and its output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can't even run `startAt(1709424900001)`, can run only this `startAt(1709424900001.toDouble())`

Comment: Finally it start working as expected, by no reason